# How to get pen input to draw?

Tags: windows-7, drawing, pen

I just got a crappy little Hyundai pen input module To use on a normal Windows 7 HP laptop, it works quite well with the Hyundai software, but that's in Chinese, and the input only stays on the screen for a second.

When I try to use it in Paint, it just draws a dot, and switches back to an unclicked state, similarly, it's impossible to move a window.

Is there ant way I can keep the click held down when the pen is touching the pad in order to draw, or is there any third party software anyone knows of that can do this?